# Apparent bug in Silverlight 4 Resource Streams or Json Xml Dictionary Reader

Tags: c#, json, silverlight

I've encountered what feels like a bug in Silverlight 4, because I can't find anything in the MSDN docs that says this shouldn't work, but it's crashing my application:

```
var info = Application.GetResourceStream(DocumentUri);

using (var stream = info.Stream)
using (var reader = JsonReaderWriterFactory.CreateJsonReader(stream, XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas.Max))
{
    // Content doesn't matter, could be empty.
}
```

The end result of this block is a `NotSupportedException` from `MS.Internal.InternalMemoryStream.Flush`. `Stream.Flush` is a bit under documented, but it would imply that the enclosing reader should call `Stream.CanSeek` and/or `Stream.CanWrite` before calling `Flush`.

If anyone else has run into this issue, I'd appreciate any references you have.

**EDIT**: I've uploaded a minimal project that's crashing here: http://sdrv.ms/x9GLNR

Comment: I can't reproduce the error you're getting.  Is it specific to certain JSON documents?

Comment: I suppose it could be, since the factory method does take a stream, but I'm not reading the stream at all, so I'd be surprised that would make a difference. But I'll do some more tests.

Comment: Post the content of the `DocumentUri` file. Maybe the json mark-up isn't valid.

Comment: I'm certain that the file is valid JSON, as the DataContractJsonSerializer can parse it. I just retested, and a minimal JSON document containing an empty object "{}" will cause the error. Looking for a place now to post my sample project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've now been able to reproduce your error.  I agree with you in that this is a bug in Silverlight.  Quite simply, there's no other reasonable explanation for a NotSupportedException being thrown from deep within classes under the `MS` or `System` namespaces.

Nonetheless, I found that your code worked if I changed the Build Action of your `document.json` file to Resource instead of Content, and changed the URI used to read the file as follows:

```
var info = Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri("/HelloApp;component/document.json", UriKind.Relative));
```

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately for many reason I can't use Resource packaging for this purpose, but I appreciate the confirmation. I've attempted to report this bug here: http://bit.ly/AkoivS